# Add WordPress blog direct sharing for Stack Overflow

Tags: feature-request, sharing

I was trying to share my question more and more using my social networks, but I do not have a lot of followers on Twitter and friends on Facebook. On the other hand, I have a **[WordPress](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/WordPress) blog**.

[image: No WordPress sharing]

I know that I can copy the given link and press this on my WordPress blog, but it would be definitely better to have a direct link to share posts on WordPress.
Can we have a link button of WordPress, like we have for `Google, Twitter and Facebook`.

---

Below the textbox we have enough space to put an image button for **WordPress sharing**.
Please consider the suggestion it may help users to get more visitors to their posts.

Answer (score 4):

### Good idea, hard to implement

How would the site know where to send it? Mind-reading? Is SE going to make a database of all users and their WP blogs? How would it know your username and password?

Other than these drawbacks, it's a great idea.

Comment: I use wordpress very often, and wordpress provides us a feature "Press this" to share a webpage directly to your blog, I believe we can have this feature on stackoverflow.

Comment: @Ðeepak That WP feature (I use it too) already knows where to send it - and has a special code so the blog trusts it. SO, on the other hand, doesn't have either.

Comment: still not getting your point, anyways it was just a suggestion because i thought it would be useful, what else i can do ?

Comment: @Ðeepak Move on - everyone here on Meta gets burned for a feature request every once in a while. Just don't get discouraged and carry on! I might have been a bit harsh. Sorry for that :)

Comment: THanks, yes you are right most of posts on meta are for feature request, I really believe it would be a good feature...

Comment: @Ðeepak And it probably would be - there are simply too many technical hurdles for the team to jump through to implement such a thing.

Comment: Yes, i can understand... Lets hope for the best

Comment: @Ðeepak Yep. I would kind of like this feature, anyway :)

Answer (score 1):

This is an interesting idea, but even if the site knew where to send the link, I would think in the large majority of cases you'd still want to edit what SO sent to your blog.

Your blog has its own voice and its own posting style.  SO is not a blog.  A well-formed question here doesn't make for a particularly good blog post, in my opinion.  In any case, people can edit your question in a way that it's not in your voice anymore.  (They shouldn't, but I've had people make judgments about my diction by making my word choices less "chatty," and the writer part of me doesn't appreciate that.)

So, even if SO did "press" your question to your blog, I'd think you'd be touching it again anyway once it got there.